# Short story about cybercriminal sentenced not to use computers

Tags: story-identification

Can anyone help me find a near-future sci fi short story I read many years ago about a hacker whose sentence was never to use computers again? I believe the sentence was enforced through an implant that made him suffer if he thought about doing so. As I recall he was on the verge of starvation because he couldn't do so much as pay for food without using a computer.

The story involved someone, maybe the narrator?, taking pity on him and buying him a meal at the diner where he'd been staring in the window or something.

It felt like perhaps Philip K. Dick or Gibson, maybe, but I could be misremembering.

Comment: My first instinct was *Neuromancer*, but the differences are a bit big - not an implant but a neurological scrambling. And he was unable to connect, not suffering if he thought about it. And he switched to being a general criminal/hustler, not on the edge of starvation. And there was no pity *anywhere*. :)

Comment: It's definitely not Neuromancer, although I can see why my description would remind you of that! I probably shouldn't have said it feels like Gibson -- it's much less gritty than that.

Answer (score 16):

This is ["A Perfect Fit"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?93597) by Isaac Asimov.

**... about a hacker whose sentence was never to use computers again**

> I have been adjusted, as you surely know, so that I am incapable of looking at a computer without hurting my eyes, or touching one without blistering my fingers. I can't even handle my cash card or even *think* of using it without nausea.

**I believe the sentence was enforced through an implant that made him suffer if he thought about doing so.**

Not an implant, but a

> combination of hypnosis and direct neuroconditioning

**As I recall he was on the verge of starvation because he couldn't do so much as pay for food without using a computer.**

> He was hungry. Periodically he was hungry.

**The story involved someone, maybe the narrator?, taking pity on him and buying him a meal at the diner where he'd been staring in the window or something.**

Not quite. He's indeed staring through the window of a restaurant, and then he's manipulating a boy to order dinner for him.

The story was first published in EDN magazine in 1981 and is available on their [website](https://www.edn.com/a-perfect-fit/). It was collected in “The Winds of Change and Other Stories” in 1983.